# Shared cookie with adfs dotnet core

Tags: c#, cookies, .net-core, adfs

I have a web which is divided in 2. I'd like to authenticate user with one and then been authentified on the other app. So I fallow the documentation to share the cookie but I'm never authenticate on the second app.

I share the Key between the 2 apps, the name of the cookie is `.AspNet.SharedCookie`.

The main problem is that I used WsFederation authentication on the first app and I'd like the second app to use cookie authentication but I've not the knowledge of what does that entail

I am using the last version of ASP.Net Core

Comment: Cookies are stored in the Browser folder on the PC under each users temporary folder.  So any application has access to read the cookies under a user account.  See : https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cookies-folder-location-windows

Comment: That doesn't answer my question and it's wrong web application can't access other credential cookies hopefully

Comment: Did you look at link?  There is nothing in the folders/filename that is associated with the application name.  It is all against the user account.